# How to use the nabla operator appropriately with cross product identities to prove a curl identity

Tags: multivariable-calculus, solution-verification, proof-writing

I'm asked to prove the following curl identity in my vector calculus class

$$ curl(curl\vec{F}) = grad(div\vec{F}) - \nabla^{2}\vec{F} \\ or \\ \nabla\times(\nabla\times\vec{F}) = \nabla(\nabla\cdot\vec{F}) - \nabla^{2}\vec{F}$$

I didn't want to brute force it, because that's no fun. I noticed the similarities between many of the curl/divergence identities and the cross/dot product identities. Below is my attempt at using a cross product identity to prove the above.

$$ Cross-Product\:Identity: \vec{A}\times (\vec{B}\times\vec{C}) =  (\vec{A}\cdot\vec{C})\vec{B} - (\vec{A}\cdot\vec{B})\vec{C} \\
\nabla\times(\nabla\times\vec{F}) = (\nabla\cdot\vec{F})\nabla - (\nabla\cdot\nabla)\vec{F} \\ \nabla\times(\nabla\times\vec{F})= grad(div\vec{F})- \nabla^{2}\vec{F}
$$

***Note:** for line 3 I moved nabla to the front of the first term on the right side of the equation.* 
My professor said it was interesting, but he couldn't approve of my use of del since it's an operator and can't just be moved without reason. *"A bit hand-wavy"* were his words. How can I justify or adjust my methods to make this a valid proof?

Comment: The fundamental issue here is that $\nabla$ is not properly a vector. It is often treated as one, and it makes for some convenient memorization techniques, but sometimes it can be sketch.

For instance, your argument assumes that $f \nabla = \nabla f$ (hence how you are getting a gradient), but this is simply not the case. It might be true for, say, a vector $\vec V$ in lieu of $\nabla$, but not for a not-quite-a-vector like $\nabla$.

Comment: @PrincessEev Pseudovector is actually a well-defined term. The cross-product of two vectors is a pseudovector.

Comment: Huh, neat, I did not know that. Thanks.

Comment: With regard to your interchange of the order, $(g\nabla)\phi = g(\nabla\phi)$, but $(\nabla g)\phi = \nabla(g\phi) = (\nabla g)\phi + g\nabla\phi$ (product rule). To make matters more suspicious, for your identity, no one cares whether you write $(A\cdot C)B$ or $B(A\cdot C)$ (although it's customary to put the scalar in front), but here we have lost that commutativity.

Comment: At any rate, you can recover such formulas "more easily" using differential forms. A vector field $\vec F$ corresponds to a $1$-form $\omega$ and the identity is $$-\Delta\omega = ({\star}d{\star}d + d{\star}d{\star})\omega,$$ with the first term corresponding to $\text{curl}(\text{curl}\,\vec F)$  and the second term to $\text{grad}(\text{div}\,\vec F)$. $\star$ is the Hodge star operator. $-\Delta$ corresponds to the "usual" Laplacian $\nabla^2$.